# Distros with hotkeys exactly the same as window$

Tags: windows, distributions

I'm new to Linux & while I don't like M$, I hate having to memorize all sets of different hotkeys for the same function. So, are there distros that have those same hotkeys? Or if there's no such distro, is there any app or soft that completely remap the hotkeys with just some clicks?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Almost all DEs have some way of defining keybindings.

Comment: I'm aware of that. For general users, especially those who have just migrated from window$, having to bind hundreds of hotkeys manually is a deal breaker.

Comment: Downvoting someone moving into Linux is productive because... Complete the sentence. What's wrong with you, people?

Comment: While migrating thousands is of course a deal breaker, a vast majority of the standard ones are present on all major Linux systems by default.  Alt-F4 still closes a window, F11 still goes full screen (that's an application hotkey though, not a Windows one), etc.  The only big ones that are typically missing are the ones that use the 'Windows' key (referred to as the 'Super' key on Linux), and most people only use a small handful of those.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Linux is the solution for you, because it supports almost every keyboard shortcuts like Win+L , Win(Called Dock in Linux), Alt+F4 etc.. and you can also assign shortcut keys manually.

This link may help you:- 
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html

Comment: I heard that ZorinOS tries to imitate windows to the extreme. Does it do so with the hotkeys also?

Comment: please take a look at this link:_ http://lnag.sourceforge.net/lnag_html/node5.html